# Symfony 6 - CAS Bundle

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas, symfony6

I am using Symfony 6 and I should use CAS bundle for my app because we use SSO system. So, can I install the following bundle while I use Symfony 6 because there is no CAS bundle for Symfony6:
https://github.com/ecphp/cas-bundle

I asked Symfony Community and I got recieved this message:

> Unfortunately, I've never worked with CAS protocol before, so don't
> use those bundles myself. But let me give you some hints. First of
> all, I see that the bundle you linked https://github.com/ecphp/ca...
> does not support Symfony 6 yet, though there's an issue about it:
> https://github.com/ecphp/ca... - feel free to follow it to know when
> that issue is closed. Also, if you have time - feel free to help with
> upgrading that bundle and make it compatible with Symfony 6 and send a
> PR - that may have a good side effect, because even if the bundle is
> slow on reviewing/merging your PR - you will be able to use *your*
> fork in your project while PR is not merged yet. Other options - you
> may want to take a look at GitHub search:
> https://github.com/search?o... - probably you will find that is still
> maintained. If no luck - you may want to use low-level tools that are
> used in those bundles to write the implementation yourself - take a
> look at composer.json file to see what libs are used behind the scene
> in those bundles that might help you. Or, another option - downgrade
> your project to Symfony 5.4. Basically, Symfony 5.4 == 6.0, but in
> Symfony 6.0 just dropped all the legacy code since 5.x version.
> Though, it might work and you will be able to install that bundle, but
> keep in mind that if the bundle is dead and nobody will add Symfony 6
> support there - you won't be able to upgrade to the newer version at
> some point.

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a CAS bundle for Symfony 6.

Take a look to
https://packagist.org/packages/l3/cas-guard-bundle
https://packagist.org/packages/l3/cas-bundle

Comment: Thank you very much @Mitja! The creater of CAS Bundle himself helped me to solve this problem. it comes from Easy Admin Bundle.